# How to use COM interop to show Excel window inside windows form

Tags: excel, c#-4.0, excel-interop

I want to display an excel inside my .net Windows Application. How can I do this using COM interop

Any help is appreciated.

Please Help ...!!

Thank You

Yohan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, COM interop does not allow you to do that.

What you can do is use the `WebBrowser` control and browse to the Excel document. This should allow you to view/edit the Excel file. There is an example [here](http://www.dotnet247.com/247reference/msgs/55/277921.aspx)